# How to use the nmcli Python module

Tags: python, python-3.x, nmcli

I'm at loss how to integrate the [python-nmcli](https://github.com/antitree/python-nmcli) module into my Python script. I seem to be fundamentally misunderstanding something about that module.

```
foo@bar:~ $ pip install python-nmcli
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Requirement already satisfied: python-nmcli in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.1.1)
```

Installed.

```
>>> from nmcli import nm
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'nm' from 'nmcli' (/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nmcli/__init__.py)
```

That is the first one should do according to the module documentation. Bummer this already fails.

```
>>> import nmcli
>>> print(nmcli)
<module 'nmcli' from '/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nmcli/__init__.py'>
```

Ok, it's properly loaded at least.

```
>>> nmcli.dev.status()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'nmcli' has no attribute 'dev'
```

It *does* [have a `dev` property](https://github.com/antitree/python-nmcli/blob/master/nmcli/nmcli.py#L127) but that one is not exposed.

```
>>> from nmcli import NMCommand
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'NMCommand' from 'nmcli' (/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nmcli/__init__.py)
```

Why can I not even import [that class](https://github.com/antitree/python-nmcli/blob/master/nmcli/nmcli.py#L32)?

Comment: did you install it via `pip install python-nmcli`?

Comment: Yes. Updated my Q now.

Comment: the package over PyPi seems a bit outdated (not even python-3 compatible). you should git-clone the repo and install it by `sudo python setup.py install`. And for some reason, it's `from nmcli.nmcli import NMCommand` not `from nmcli import NMCommand` as it's written in their README)

Comment: but overall it seems unmaintained and dead, I wouldn't recommend you use it.

Comment: Switched over to https://github.com/fbarresi/PyNmcli. That one works as advertised.

Comment: Btw, the one on PyPi is a different fork, the parent of the one I was using. I just didn't realize until you pointed me to it.